# A Birthday Gift for You

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Happy belated (or early!) birthday to everyone!

[image: Birthday Gift]

Comment: thanks but it's not my birthday until next year...

Comment: Aww, my birthday was exactly a week ago. Should have made this earlier. :P

Comment: I actually just bought a 55 inch TV for my birthday yesterday!

Comment: +1 for zero-indexing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Building off the other answers (thanks UselessInfoMine and N'Katar), I think I have them all worked out.

1:

> DIE, TOYS, SAD (as noted above)
>  [image]

2:

> TSAR, SUM (MUST without its end and reversed), REN (Sophia LoREN). 
>  [image]

3:

> HANG (within "sHANGhai" or abduct), LOL (head of LOLLIPOP), KEG (EKG anagram)
>  [image]

For the grids:

> Place the answers in their corresponding colored spaces, first letter going in 0, second in 1, etc.

Then:

> Stack the grids so that three apropos phrases read down: MATROYSHKA, NESTED DOLL and RUSSIAN EGG.

I think that's all.

Comment: You seem to have Rot13(FUNATUNV)'d the victory, but there Rot13(ZHFG) be a better alternative for "imperative."

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll add those to my answer.

Answer (score 15):

Aha!

> I downloaded it, and I opened it. :)
> I opened it with 7-zip. Inside I found:

1. > 1clues.png which appears to be some weird crossword-ish puzzle.
   >  [image: 1clues.png]
2. > Another, smaller box gif called outfile2.gif, which contained:
3. > 2clues.png which is another puzzle like 1clues.png
   >  [image: 2clues.png]
4. > Another, even smaller box gif called outfile1.gif, which contained:
5. > 3clues.png which is a third, similar puzzle.
   >  [image: 3clues.png]

> 1clues.png's clues are as follows:
> Check out the start of this nutritionist's advice!
> Walrus and Carpenter action figures remove their preys head and scramble it.
> Despondency found in grievous adolescents

To which my answers are:

> Nut
> Eggs
> Sad
> However, I'm not sure how they fit in the grid. I tried the obvious way, colours and numbers in order, but I get nothing in the grid.

Next bit:

> 2clues.png's clues are as follows:
> Capital punishment for his part in the abduction
> Sucker head is showing amusement
> Life of the party's heart activity is abnormal

To which my answers are:

> No idea.
> No idea.
> No idea.

Followed by:

> 3clues.png's clues are as follows:
> Inside cats are ruling people
> Addition imperative without footnotes is coming back
> Animated dog removes actress Sophia's top

To which my answers are:

> Tsar
> No idea.
> No idea, but could be something along the lines of Snoopy -Sop (Sophia's top) = noy?

Comment: What did you find? A surprise? :-)

Comment: I did. I shall update in a moment. I'm stuck at work so poking in between tasks.

Comment: The walrus and the carpenter are taken from Alice in wonderland - how's that pearl of a hint?

Answer (score 11):

This gift is beginning to feel like celebrating

> the [GIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF) Graphics Interchange Format that was developed by a team at CompuServe led by the computer scientist Steve Wilhite on June 15, 1987 - today (or yesterday in some countries).

Comment: Well, that's *swell,* but [Brad Pitt wants to know more.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ue1-lnHVkpQ)

Answer (score 7):

After opening the actual image file as a(n)

> 7-Zip archive, and nested in the gift is another gift, all matryoshka-like.

You eventually get three small cryptic... crosswords?

> Thanks for uploading them UselessInfoMine, [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKZ8C.png), [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89zVf.png), [three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1gYm.png)

Which seem to imply the following clues:

Block 1

> Check out the start of this nutritionist's advice! (3)
>  Walrus and Carpenter action figures remove their preys head and scramble it. (4)
>  Despondency found in grievous adolescents (3)

Block 2

> Capital punishment for his part in the abduction (4)
>  Sucker head is showing amusement (3)
>  Life of the party's heart activity is abnormal (3)

Block 3

> Inside cats are ruling people (4)
>  Addition imperative without footnotes is coming back (3)
>  Animated dog removes actress Sophia's top (3)

Which I don't know all the answers to, but have partial insight:

> Check out the start of this nutritionist's advice! (3)
>  Nutritionists advise to DIET, the start of which is **DIE**, which certainly is to "check out"
>
>  Walrus and Carpenter action figures remove their preys head and scramble it. (4)
>  Lewis Carroll says that the two prey on OYSTERS (head OYST), but as action figures they are **TOYS**
>
>  Despondency found in grievous adolescents (3)
>  Possibly as simple as GRIEVOU**SAD**OLESCENTS
>
>  Capital punishment for his part in the abduction (4)
>  Hanging someone with a **ROPE** is capital punishment, and possible part of APP**ROP**RIAT**E** (A stretch)
>
>  Inside cats are ruling people (4)
>  CA**TSAR**E
>
>  Addition imperative without footnotes is coming back (3)
>  To come back is to **RET**URN, the key of which you can use to finish an addition on your calculator  (Another stretch)
>
>  Animated dog removes actress Sophia's top (3)
>  Remove the top of [SOPHIA LO**REN**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophia_Loren) and you're left with the other half of Stimpy

Comment: "Sucker head is showing amusement" could be rot13(yby orpnhfr vg vf gur urnq bs ybyyvcbc).